# How to call EventEmitter on click event with HighCharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to emit the clicked series.

Unfortunately, when I'm into the function click, I  don't have access to my class object. `this` is refered to the `Chart` object.

So does some of you know how to call an Event emitter from a clicked serie ?

Something like this :

```js
@Output() service = new EventEmitter<any>();

ngOnInit() {
    // Initialition of Chart ...
    this.trend = new Chart({
        chart : { ... }
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                click: () => { this.service.emit(this.series.userOptions); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` because emit is not known inside `click`

Comment: you should add more source code to question

Comment: I edited but I put only the needed code. What do you want more ?

Comment: with your code it is not easy to know what problem

Comment: You can try the old trick: define `const that = this;` at the start of `ngOnInit`, and use `that.service.emit(that.series.userOptions)`.

Comment: @Emilien What is the code you have already tried? If you can - please add a live demo. Fat arrow functions should preserve the `this` context from previous scope, so why is the expected code not working for you? You could have both if you could store the `chart` instance for later reference in the higher scope - e.g. from chart's callback where the `chart` instance is provided as first argument.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yeah it's working ! I don't know if it's a good solution, but for now it's working :) Thanks a lot to everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

Setup your `click` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Initialition of Chart ...
    this.trend = new Chart({
        chart : { ... }
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                click: this.emitValue.bind(this) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now define `emitValue()` in your component class like this:

```
emitValue() {
  this.service.emit(this.series.userOptions);
}
```

Comment: It couldn't work because `series` is not a property of my component. I have access to this value only inside the `click` event.
Moreover, inside `click` event, `this` refere to Chart Object, and not to my component.